# Hiding uib popover on button click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Anchor tag on  which html popover

```
<a popover-trigger="outsideClick" popover-placement="top" ng-click="sendMessagePopover.open()" type="button" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-is-open="sendMessagePopover.isOpen" uib-popover-template="sendMessagePopover.templateUrl">Menu</a>
```

ng-Template that contains close button on which click popover should close.

```
<script  type="text/ng-template" id="message-to-pnd-popover.tpl.html">
<div class="well">
    <form name="myForm"  ng-controller="myController">
       <div class="form-group">
            <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMessagePopover.close()">Close</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div></script>
```

angular controller code

```
angular.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.sendMessagePopover = {
            on: false,
            isOpen: false,
            templateUrl: 'message-to-pnd-popover.tpl.html',
            open: function() {
                $scope.sendMessagePopover.isOpen = true;
            },
            close: function() {
                $scope.sendMessagePopover.isOpen = false;
            }
        }]);
```

When we click on anchor link it popover the template and when we click outside anywhere it close the popover.

I want to close the popover when user click on close button that i put in template.
But it's  not working.

I am new this technology, help out with proper example.

Comment: can we have the controller code too ? I mean the function head and such ? so that we have the whole context ?

Comment: you are trying to close the popover on another buttons click?

Comment: yes @naveen . I log that value to console to check and it is false or  not. And log output "false". But popover is not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

The popover-trigger="outsideClick" is designed to close the popover when clicking anywhere outside of the popover content.  If you want to manage opening and closing the popover using the is-open attribute, use popover-trigger="none".

Comment: i tried as you mentioned above but still not working :( . I have similar template for another task and on cancel button click it's  that popover. But it's totally strange not working on another task/control.

Comment: If you can create a plunk that demonstrates the problem, I'd be happy to look into it further.